# Connecting LAN Subnet to GCP VM Subnet (VM Windows File Server)

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, vpn, fileserver

So a little background of what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm basically trying to setup a Windows File Server using GCP VM Windows Instance. I have the VM setup and I have created a VPN connection between our office network and to the GCP VM network.

Now I'm trying to communicate between the two different subnets and I have to admit I'm kinda lost.

My office subnet is 192.168.72.0/24 and my GCP IP is 10.123.0.0 with my server being at 10.123.0.2

If I understand networking correctly I need to setup a route between 192.168.72.0 to 10.123.0.2? Or do I just need to create a firewall rule?

I'm using a SonicWall Firewall to establish the VPN connection to the GCP network.

I think I've been working at this too long for one day. I'm steaping away for a bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is now a non issue, this is being automatically done by my firewall, which was the purpose of creating the VPN tunnel in the first place.

Comment: Have you already solved the issue? If yes please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a Site to Site, you should not need to include a route, you will if you setup a Tunnel Interface.  But to me, it sounds like you just need to do a site to site.  I dont think the tunnel will come up without the correct subnets, but just verify that the tunnel is up and then I would setup a packet monitor to see what route the traffic is taking when you try to ping from 192.168.72.0/24 to IP is 10.123.0.0.